# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_55_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 48, 48, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, conv-neural-network

I am new to ml/ai and I am trying to build a cnn+lstm but am struggling with the lstm's shape. I am passing 48 x 48 grayscale images through with a batch size of 10 using ImageDataGenerator. It is binary classification (either a or b). The images themselves are frames of a video which i am trying to run through such that it better understands the sequence of the frames as it relates to the prediction of the whole video. The cnn by itself works, but when i add the lstm i get an error.

Here's my code:

```
cnn = Sequential()

num_timesteps = 2

# 1st conv layer
cnn.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), padding='same', input_shape=(48, 48, 1)))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

# 2nd conv layer
cnn.add(Conv2D(128,(5,5), padding='same'))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

# 3rd conv layer
cnn.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3), padding='same'))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

# 4th conv layer
cnn.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3), padding='same'))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

# flatten
cnn.add(Flatten())

# fully connected 1
cnn.add(Dense(256))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

#fully connected 2
cnn.add(Dense(512))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))


model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn, input_shape=(None, 48, 48, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(num_timesteps))
model.add(Dropout(0.2)) 
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
```

The error that occurs when I run `model.fit` is :

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_56_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (10, 48, 48, 1)

I have tried to add the number of timesteps to the dimensions but that doesn't seem to work.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a reshape layer, and change the input shape thereafter:

```
model.add(Reshape((1, 48, 48, 1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn, input_shape=(1, 48, 48, 1)))
```

Full working example:

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
import numpy as np


cnn = Sequential()

num_timesteps = 2

# 1st conv layer
cnn.add(Conv2D(8,(3,3), padding='same', input_shape=(48, 48, 1)))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

# 2nd conv layer
cnn.add(Conv2D(8,(5,5), padding='same'))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

# 3rd conv layer
cnn.add(Conv2D(8,(3,3), padding='same'))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

# 4th conv layer
cnn.add(Conv2D(8,(3,3), padding='same'))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

# flatten
cnn.add(Flatten())

# fully connected 1
cnn.add(Dense(8))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))

#fully connected 2
cnn.add(Dense(8))
cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
cnn.add(Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))


model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((1, 48, 48, 1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn, input_shape=(1, 48, 48, 1)))
model.add(LSTM(num_timesteps))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])

model.fit(np.random.rand(100, 48, 48, 1), np.random.rand(100))
```